# Error when converting from HSV to BGR, or HSV to JPEG in openCV after using inRange

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I am using openCV 3.1.0 (I have tried with 2.4.9, with same problem). I want to output a HSV mat to jpeg:

```
// .. Getting JPEG content into memory
// JPEG to mat
Mat imgBuf=Mat(1, jpegContent, CV_8UC3, jpegSize);
Mat imgMat=imdecode(imgBuf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
free(jpegContent);
if(imgMat.data == NULL) {
    // Some error handling
}
// Now the JPEG is decoded and reside in imgMat
cvtColor(imgMat, imgMat, CV_BGR2HSV); // Converting to HSV
Mat tmp;
inRange(imgMat, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(8, 8, 8), tmp); // Problem goes here
cvtColor(tmp, imgMat, CV_HSV2BGR);
// Mat to JPEG
vector<uchar> buf;
imencode(".jpg", imgMat, buf, std::vector<int>());
outputJPEG=(unsigned char*)malloc(buf.size());
memcpy(outputJPEG, &buf[0], buf.size());
// ... Output JPEG
```

The problem is, when i do `cvtColor(tmp, imgMat, CV_HSV2BGR)` with `inRange`, my program will fail with:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cvtColor, file /home/pi/opencv/src/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 8176
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/pi/opencv/src/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:8176: error: (-215) scn == 3 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cvtColor

If i removed `inRange`, the program work just fine. I have tried to remove the cvtColor call, letting `imencode` to do its job, automatically converting HSV to BGR then to JPEG. This time, no more assertion failed, but i got corrupted JPEG image, as GStreamer complains:

> gstrtpjpegpay.c(581): gst_rtp_jpeg_pay_read_sof ():
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0
>   WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGPay:rtpjpegpay0: Wrong SOF length 11.

Again, removing `inRange` also solves this issue, it produces good JPEG data.

So, is that i am invoking `inRange` improperly that cause corrupted image data? If yes, what is the correct way to use `inRange`?

Comment: `inRange` gives you a binary matrix of type `CV_8UC1`. You cannot convert it to HSV

Comment: It works pretty well now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inRange` produces a single channel binary matrix, i.e. a `CV_8UC1` matrix with values either `0` or `255`.

So you cannot convert `tmp` with `HSV2BGR`, because the source image `tmp` doesn't have 3 channels.

OpenCV is telling you exactly this: *scn* (source channels) is not 3.

---

Since you probably want to keep and then convert to BGR only part of the image in your range, you can:

1. set to black everything outside the range: `imgMat.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0), ~tmp);`
2. convert the resulting image to BGR: `cvtColor(imgMat, imgMat, CV_HSV2BGR);`