# Java OpenCV convert HSV back to BGR after inRange

Tags: java, opencv, jframe

I'd like to create a black&white image relying on HSV filtering. However, after converting the image from BGR to HSV and applying the `inRange()` method, the matrix is reduced to a single channel matrix (with values either `0` or `255`) and cannot be converted back to BGR.

Is there an easy way to work around this? Do I even need that step of back-conversion or can I somehow display the new image with the information I have? I'm pretty new to OpenCV  and  already found a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922555/error-when-converting-from-hsv-to-bgr-or-hsv-to-jpeg-in-opencv-after-using-inra) but I'm still kinda confused on what to do.

Example:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(path);
Mat hsv = new Mat();
Mat img_new = new Mat(); 

Imgproc.cvtColor(img,hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
Core.inRange(hsv, new Scalar(hue,saturation,value),new Scalar(hue,saturation,value),hsv);
Imgproc.cvtColor(hsv, img_new, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2BGR); // This line doesn't work.

// display new image in JFrame
MatOfByte mob = new MatOfByte();
Imgcodecs.imencode(".tif", img_new, mob);
byte ba[] = mob.toArray();
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba));
newImgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon (bi));
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inRange function gives you a mask(actually, a single channel image with values 0 and 255), you can use it to select which areas you want to select.

```
Mat mask = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(img,hsv,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
Core.inRange(hsv, new Scalar(hue,saturation,value),new Scalar(hue,saturation,value),mask);
img.copyTo(img_new, mask);
```

Comment: This works like a charm - thank you kindly! Edit: to get my black&white image I did the following now: `Mat template = img.clone(); template.setTo(new Scalar(255,255,255)); template.copyTo(img_new, mask);`